# Show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, Dom f = [a, \infty), a > 0$ is a Lipschitz function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show that $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2}, Dom f = [a, \infty), a > 0$$ is a Lipschitz function.

So far I have that if a function is Lipschitz then there exists a constant $K > 0$, such that $|f(x) - f(y)| \le K|x - y| \forall x,y\in[a, \infty)$.

$|f(x) - f(y)| = |\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2}| = \frac{|y^2 - x^2|}{x^2y^2} = \frac{|x - y||x + y|}{x^2y^2} \le |x - y|(\frac{|x|}{x^2y^2} + \frac{|y|}{x^2y^2})$

 This is where I'm not too sure if I'm going about this correctly

$|x - y|(\frac{|x|}{x^2y^2} + \frac{|y|}{x^2y^2}) \le |x - y|(\frac{|x|}{x^2} + \frac{|y|}{y^2}) \le |x - y|(\frac{|a|}{a^2} + \frac{|a|}{a^2}) = |x - y|(\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{a})$ 
$= |x - y|(\frac{2}{a})$.

So $|f(x) - f(y)| \le K|x - y|$ with $K$ being $\frac{1}{a}$. Therefore f(x) is Lipschitz on $[a, \infty)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your first step, $$|x - y|\left(\frac{|x|}{x^2y^2} + \frac{|y|}{x^2y^2}\right) \le |x - y|\left(\frac{|x|}{x^2} + \frac{|y|}{y^2}\right)$$ which does not necesarily hold. If $x$ and $y$ are both larger than $1$, then the inverse of the inequality holds.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

$$\exists\,c\in (x,y)\;\;s.t.\;\;\left|\frac{\frac1{x^2}-\frac1{y^2}}{x-y}\right|=\left|\frac2{c^3}\right|\le\left|\frac2{a^3}\right|$$